# Integration of half vectorization of a matrix

Tags: integration, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

Given a matrix P_[nxn] which is symmetric and I want to integrate its product say A_[nxn]*P[nxn] using an integrator that takes in vectors only. I read up on vectorization process and landed on the Matrix differential book by Magnus and Neudecker which gives me this helpful formula

$\dot{P}_{3\times3} = A_{n\times n}\times P_{3\times3}$
after vectorization
$\dot{P}_{9\times1} = [A_{n\times n}\bigotimes I_{3}]\times P_{9\times1}$

But in my case the P matrix is symmetric, so I don't need to integrate the lower triangle of the P matrix, so anyone can help me with a formula to evaluate the vectorization operator for the upper or lower triangle of the matrix? Instead of the kronecker product which vectorizes the whole matrix. This means that my P matrix will be reduced to 6 elements(in the upper triangle) and my transformed A matrix will be a 6x6 matrix instead of 9x9.

Edit: I want to point out that i want to force the matrix integrand to be symmetric.

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate" ? Make increasing summations ?

Comment: yes something of that sort, because P and A are time dependent matrices

Comment: $
\def\vc{\operatorname{vec}}
\def\vh{\operatorname{vech}}
$Since you have Magnus and Neudecker, go back and read the chapter on the Duplication Matrix $(D_n)$ 
$$\eqalign{
\vc(\dot P) &= (A\otimes I)\,\vc(P) \quad
  \iff\quad \vh(\dot P) = D_n^+(A\otimes I)\,D_n\vh(P) \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, Greg, you have solved my problem. You are an amazing person.